# Highcharts/Highmaps : Show bubblemap in drilldown

Tags: jquery, highcharts, drilldown, highmaps

I need to show world map as bubblemap using highcharts. At level 1, showing world map with bubbles on countries on basis of data.

Here's the fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamesh_prasad/3yc3m6q8/).

Next thing I want is to show bubblemap for countries if country is selected by clicking any of bubble. Till now I'm able to load bubble layer passing ID in first series for drilldown. But, I also need to show another series for loading back map to display bubble on it, at same time drilldown is called for any country. 
Tried passing multiple ID in drilldown of first series, as:

```
drilldown: ["US", "US2"]
```

but, no getting anywhere, also is it possible to show bubblemap in drilldown ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, could you please check your link to JSFiddle? It appears to be broken.

Comment: Unfortunately drilldown to multiple series is not supported, but we have plans to add this. Right now you can develop workaround by adding and removing series using simple chart.addSeries(). If you are going to implement this workaround then this forum thread might be helpful for you - http://forum.highcharts.com/post109761.html

Comment: Thanks Kacper, I surely will work around this. If this worked will be posting solution here.